# MYSQL use 'LIKE' in 'WHERE' clause to search in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause, sql-like

How would you use 'LIKE' to search in a subquery?

E.g. i've tried doing this, but doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE name
    LIKE '%
        (SELECT name FROM myothertable)
        %'
```

---

I have this so far:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE t1.name IN (SELECT t2.name FROM t2)
AND (t1.title IN (SELECT t2.title FROM t2)
    OR t1.surname IN (SELECT t2.surname FROM t2))
```

It's working ok as it returns exact matchs, but it doesn't seem to return my other records that are similar, so I would like to also check that:
t1.title LIKE '%t2.title%' AND t1.surname LIKE '%t2.surname%'
How would i do this?

Comment: How many rows does your `myothertable` have?

Comment: only two little correction in your code. 1st remove % and like.Second add in after name, full code is in my answer.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR SPEEDY RESPONSES SO FAR ^_^.

    @zerkms - about 10 but this doesn't really affect what i'm trying to do, i just want to compare a few fields.

Comment: @Jason_vorhees - I've edited your response to include what I have tried to do so far. What I want to do now is to try and do a query for LIKE '% %'

Comment: you cannot do like this "LIKE '%(SELECT name FROM myothertable)%'" try `IN` instead of LIKE.

Answer (score 35):

Using a JOIN:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM mytable a
  JOIN myothertable b ON a.name LIKE CONCAT('%', b.name, '%')
```

...but there could be duplicates, if there's more than one match in `myothertable` for a given `mytable` record.

Using EXISTS:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM mytable a
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                 FROM myothertable b 
                WHERE a.name LIKE CONCAT('%', b.name, '%'))
```

Using [Full Text Search `MATCH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html) (requires `myothertable` is MyISAM)

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM mytable a
  JOIN myothertable b ON MATCH(a.name) AGAINST (b.name)
```

Comment: @bernie: I give options, but EXISTS is probably the best choice -- you were first, +1

Comment: Perfect answer. Just a small note: `MATCH` probably could produce not actually expected result

Answer (score 13):

For example:

```
SELECT a_column
FROM   mytable t
WHERE  EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM   myothertable ot
           WHERE  t.`name` LIKE '%' || ot.`name` || '%');
```

As far as terminology goes: this is known as a correlated subquery.

Comment: And if we go further - every subquery in mysql is correlated ;-) (or more precise: optimizer rewrites every subquery to a correlated one)

Comment: @zerkms: `EXISTS` doesn't execute as a correlated subquery

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Ok, but I didn't say it does ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: I'm doing my best to implicate you? :p

Comment: @OMG Ponies: yep ;-) Btw, that information was really interesting. I always thought that `EXISTS` is optimized in the similar way to `IN (subquery)`

Comment: @zerkms: Some ways, yes.  But EXISTS doesn't care what happens in the SELECT clause, and short-circuits on the first match which makes it a better choice if there's duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

this string works fine for me.

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field like CONCAT('%', (SELECT id FROM table2), '%')";
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the inner select returns more than one row

Answer (score 2):

Just another way:

```
select a.field, b.code
from table1 a 
inner join (select code from table2 where ....) b on a.field like CONCAT('%', b.code, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to create function called  NameMatch()

Final Query :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable  WHERE dbo.NameMatch(name) = 1
```

The function would look like :

```
create function dbo.NameMatch 
(@_name varchar(100))
returns bit 
as  begin

    declare @res bit 
    if exists (select 1 from myothertable where @_name like '%' + name + '%' )
     set @res = 1
    else set @res  = 0
    return @res

end
```

Comment: No - this actually would execute Row By Agonizing Row (RBAR).  SQL is SET based...

Comment: You can try running above on MSSQL 2000/2005/2008. It works fine. I just did the same.

Comment: "Working" does mean "performs as efficiently as it could".  And the question is MySQL, not SQL Server...

Answer (score 0):

It Worked FOR ME

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE name
LIKE CONCAT('%',(SELECT name FROM myothertable),'%')
```

Comment: On MySQL 5.6 this query throws Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row. What version did you run this on?

Comment: Dear Make Sure your subquery return only one record. otherwise it will not work

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM t1
WHERE t1.name IN (SELECT t2.name FROM t2)
AND (t1.title IN (SELECT t2.title FROM t2)
    OR t1.surname IN (SELECT t2.surname FROM t2))
```