# mySQL first select results used as a LIKE for second select

Tags: php, mysql

have two tables what i would like to do is run a select against one and the results it returns use that for a second select query on a different table

My first select is

```
SELECT classes FROM hodnames where initials ='".$_SESSION['username']."' order by id DESC
```

Which returns two results back, which i would like to use on a second select query, to complicate things further to get the second set results the first set must be used with a LIKE as for example the first set may return "En" and "Ma" the second set of results contains those eg "10MA/1" "10EN/1"

```
SELECT classes FROM classlist where classes LIKE='results_from_first_query' order by id DESC
```

I have a select box that is populated by a select query but would like to restrict it to results the user is allowed to have access to.

As you can see it will return more then 1 row.

Thanks for your help

Comment: refer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/98565/100546

Comment: doesn't seem to work as the results return more then 1 row

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022338/mysql-use-like-in-where-clause-to-search-in-subquery